# What does "manifest path is a virtual manifest, but this command requires running against an actual package" mean?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to build a Rust project (xray). When running `cargo run` I get the following error message

> error: manifest path `D:\xray\building\xray\Cargo.toml` is a virtual
> manifest, but this command requires running against an actual package
> in this workspace

What exactly does this mean and how can it be solved? I'm using Cargo version 0.25.0 and Rust version 1.24.1.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your `Cargo.toml` is a [*virtual manifest*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#virtual-manifest).

> In workspace manifests, if the `package` table is present, the workspace root crate will be treated as a normal package, as well as a workspace. If the `package` table is not present in a workspace manifest, it is called a *virtual manifest*.
>
> When working with *virtual manifests*, package-related cargo commands, like `cargo build`, won't be available anymore. But, most of such commands support the `--all` option, will execute the command for all the non-virtual manifest in the workspace.

`cargo run` does not work, because cargo doesn't know *what* to run. There are two options:

1. `--manifest-path <PATH>`: Path to `Cargo.toml` of the crate you want to run.
2. `-p, --package <SPEC>`: Package you want to run.

In your case it's probably `cargo run --package xray_cli`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I have an examples folder of local libraries that are each sub folders and their own Cargo.toml files. This worked great.

Answer (score -3):

the manifest has both package and workspace sections can't works. please check the Cargo.toml and remove package from it.

[Virtual Manifest](https://github.com/behnam/rust-cargo/blob/3f5ca7b53f2fbf098dc6b60069fc1335b81727af/src/doc/manifest.md) is new concepts, please reading docs to familiar it. Hope it values for you.